# Missing fields after migration in Django project

Tags: python, django, migration

I am interested in learning python and Django and I've started [this course](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html).
I am having difficulties in migrating the models in the project. Following the course, on chapter "Models".

I've inserted the given code in the boards/models.py file as instructed. The code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+')`
```

Following the instructions to the "Migrating the Models" chapter and running this command:
"python manage.py makemigrations" I should receive the following message:

Migrations for 'boards':
boards/migrations/0001_initial.py
- Create model Board
- Create model Post
- Create model Topic
- Add field topic to post
- Add field updated_by to post

Instead, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in     execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in     execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Zinkov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in     import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\myproject\boards\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "D:\Desktop\myproject\myproject\boards\models.py", line 11, in Topic
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'`
```

I've added the missing argument "on_delete" on the following lines:

```
board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts',max_length=256, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+',max_length=256, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

After running the "makemigrations" command again the migration was successful but without adding the fields as expected.
My output is:

Migrations for 'boards':
boards\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Board
- Create model Topic
- Create model Post

Instead of:

Migrations for 'boards':
boards\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Board
- Create model Topic
- Create model Post
- Add field topic to post
- Add field updated_by to post

I am sorry for the long post.
Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is the correct output and you have solved the issue you had. I think that the "Add field ..." lines are shown when you add additional fields to an existing model.

Answer (score 0):

While creating model where you have used ForeignKey relation it accepts on_delete argument and that is missing. Adding it should work.
Kindly refer to below code

```
class Topic(models.Model):
     subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

You can refer to this link for more on_delete arguments [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-relational-fields-in-django-models/]

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!

After the corrections and running the migration command it popped an error.

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
boards.Topic.board: (fields.E320) Field specifies on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True argument on the field, or change the on_delete rule.
boards.Topic.starter: (fields.E320) Field specifies on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True argument on the field, or change the on_delete rule.
I've added the 'null=True' and the migrations were successful